# R DiagrammeR Flush Subscript and Superscript within Labels

Tags: r, diagrammer

Long time reader, first time poster.

I am attempting to write mechner notation using DiagrammeR (through R Studio; everything is up to date; MacOS). Long term intention is to embed the code within a latex doc, but I'm taking this one step at a time. Currently, I cannot find the code necessary to force a subscript and superscript to be in-line with each other. So far, I have found this:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("
  digraph dot {

  graph [layout = dot, rankdir = LR]

  node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = plaintext]
  a [label = 'aA']
  b [label = 'bA@_{2}@^{p}']
  c [label = 'abC']

  a -> b -> c
  }")
```

[Produces this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtwyM.png)
[But I need this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgRRd.jpg)
I suppose the real question is how to properly format within those pesky quotations. I have yet to find a walkthrough on how to properly format (e.g., bold, italics, superscript) within the label field quotations. Suggestions?

Comment: Where is the notation '*@_{*}' documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out and forgot to post an answer! Here is the code that worked for me (Mac OSx; R Studio Sweave File, w/ pdfLaTeX enabled):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\1}{\textbf} %to save space

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

%example 1
\par{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, row 
sep=1em,column sep=2em,minimum width=4em,nodes={anchor=center}]
  {
  a\1{A} & b\1{A}_{2}^{p} & ab\1{C} & \\
  };
  \draw [->] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-2);
  \draw [->] (m-1-2) -- (m-1-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\par}

%example 2
\par{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, row 
sep=1em,column sep=2em,minimum width=4em,nodes={anchor=center}]
  {
  t\1{S}_{A}^{D} & s\1{R}_{CR} & t\1{S}_{CR} & \\
  };
  \draw [->] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-2);
  \draw [->] (m-1-2) -- (m-1-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\par}

\end{document}
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oRQ7.png)